# Entity Framework Error: ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following method:

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(AmazonProduct amazonProduct)
    {
        var product = context.AmazonProducts
                        .Include(x => x.AmazonLowestOfferListings)
                        .Include(x => x.AmazonMyPrices)
                        .Include(x => x.AmazonProductCompetitivePrices)
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ASIN == amazonProduct.ASIN);

        if (product == null)
        {
            // New entity
            context.AmazonProducts.Add(amazonProduct);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var lineItem in amazonProduct.AmazonLowestOfferListings)
            {
                context.AmazonLowestOfferListings.Add(lineItem);
            }

            context.Entry(product).CurrentValues.SetValues(amazonProduct);
        }
    }
```

But on the line,

```
foreach (var lineItem in amazonProduct.AmazonLowestOfferListings)
```

it gives me the error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

I dont get it..  I havent even added it to the context yet, and it still gives me this error?  Any one any idea?

thanks
Neil

Comment: Did you include `AmazonLowestOfferListings` in the `amazonProduct` passed to that method ? EF may be trying to lazy-load that collection, which needs a connection that has been disposed in this context.

Comment: I cant, as AmazonProduct is just an object at that point.  I havent added it to the context yet, if you know what i mean?

Comment: Where does the value for the amazonProduct parameter come from? Its context may have been disposed of, therefore you can't enumerate its AmazonLowestOfferListings

Comment: its just a POCO i created and passed to the InsertOrUpdate() method of my repository

Comment: Sorry!! you are correct.. i forgot i Find() this product previously... thank you so much!

Comment: If I had a dollar each time that error poped up... I've posted my original comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include `AmazonLowestOfferListings` in the `amazonProduct` passed to that method ?

EF may be trying to lazy-load that collection, which needs a connection that has been disposed in this context.